# ServiceWorker - Cache all failed post requests when offline and resubmit when online

Tags: javascript, service-worker

My service worker at the moment successfully achieves the following:

- It caches all pages visited when online
- It only returns cached pages when offline

My application has the ability for users to input signatures, which are submitted via ajax automatically. I am attempting to capture this post request in my service worker when they're offline, and resubmit the same request as soon as they're online.

Below is a sample of my serviceworker file.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    // Intercept all fetch requests from the parent page
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
        .then(function(response) {
            // Immediately respond if request exists in the cache and user is offline
            if (response && !navigator.onLine) {
                return response;
            }


            // IMPORTANT: Clone the request. A request is a stream and
            // can only be consumed once. Since we are consuming this
            // once by cache and once by the browser for fetch, we need
            // to clone the response
            var fetchRequest = event.request.clone();

            // Make the external resource request
            return fetch(fetchRequest).then(
                function(response) {
                // If we do not have a valid response, immediately return the error response
                // so that we do not put the bad response into cache
                if (!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
                    return response;
                }

                // IMPORTANT: Clone the response. A response is a stream
                // and because we want the browser to consume the response
                // as well as the cache consuming the response, we need
                // to clone it so we have 2 stream.
                var responseToCache = response.clone();

                // Place the request response within the cache
                caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
                .then(function(cache) {
                    if(event.request.method !== "POST")
                    {
                        cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
                    }
                });

                return response;
            }
            );
        })
    );
});
```

I am trying to figure out the best way to incorporate this? Is anyone able to shed some light?

Comment: Have you tried creating an array of offline requests? Iterate array when user is online?

Comment: @guest271314 at the moment I'm working on store all requests where the URL contains my save signature url. I'm not sure how to approach resubmitting these requests from the service worker when online.

Comment: @guest271314 I'm also having trouble caching the contents of the post from inside the service worker. the event.request object seems to be devoid of the POST contents.

Comment: What do you mean by "devoid of the POST contents"? Where do you check  `response` for `body` of `POST`?

Comment: @guest271314 I've updated my post - at the top I am pushing a request object to callsToCache array. I've been inspecting these objects, and they contains a lot of information about the post request but not the formdata inside the request.

Comment: `javascript` at Question does not process `response` to return `FormData` object

Comment: @guest271314 is there any other method of getting this or should I convert my signature calls to GET requests?

Comment: @guest271314 I have updated my post as I have found a way of retrieving the POST formdata.

Comment: _"I have updated my post as I have found a way of retrieving the POST formdata."_ Does this resolve Question?

Comment: @guest271314 Still working on a way to resubmit these requests but there's a good chance I'll be able to work it out myself from this point.

Comment: @guest271314 Got it all working as desired. Updated post, thanks for your help.

Comment: Consider reverting Question to original and answering own Question with updated Answer? See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks I have done this, I cannot accept my own answer for 2 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have achieved my desired result with the following code underneath the following comments.

```
// Cache signature post request
    //This retrieves all the information about the POST request including the formdata body, where the URL contains updateSignature.
// Resubmit offline signature requests
    //This resubmits all cached POST results and then empties the array.

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    // Intercept all fetch requests from the parent page
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
        .then(function(response) {
            // Cache signature post request
            if (event.request.url.includes('updateSignature') && !navigator.onLine) {
                var request = event.request;
                var headers = {};
                for (var entry of request.headers.entries()) {
                    headers[entry[0]] = entry[1];
                }
                var serialized = {
                    url: request.url,
                    headers: headers,
                    method: request.method,
                    mode: request.mode,
                    credentials: request.credentials,
                    cache: request.cache,
                    redirect: request.redirect,
                    referrer: request.referrer
                };
                request.clone().text().then(function(body) {
                    serialized.body = body;
                    callsToCache.push(serialized);
                    console.log(callsToCache);
                });     
            }
            // Immediately respond if request exists in the cache and user is offline
            if (response && !navigator.onLine) {
                return response;
            }
            // Resubmit offline signature requests
            if(navigator.onLine && callsToCache.length > 0) {
                callsToCache.forEach(function(signatureRequest) {
                    fetch(signatureRequest.url, {
                        method: signatureRequest.method,
                        body: signatureRequest.body
                    })
                });
                callsToCache = [];
            }


            // IMPORTANT: Clone the request. A request is a stream and
            // can only be consumed once. Since we are consuming this
            // once by cache and once by the browser for fetch, we need
            // to clone the response
            var fetchRequest = event.request.clone();

            // Make the external resource request
            return fetch(fetchRequest).then(
                function(response) {
                // If we do not have a valid response, immediately return the error response
                // so that we do not put the bad response into cache
                if (!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
                    return response;
                }

                // IMPORTANT: Clone the response. A response is a stream
                // and because we want the browser to consume the response
                // as well as the cache consuming the response, we need
                // to clone it so we have 2 stream.
                var responseToCache = response.clone();

                // Place the request response within the cache
                caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
                .then(function(cache) {
                    if(event.request.method !== "POST")
                    {
                        cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
                    }
                });

                return response;
            }
            );
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: Where is `callsToCache`  defined? I read somewhere that one  should not use global variables because they can be lost at anypoint.

Comment: May help others too: some similar code can be found here: `https://github.com/mozilla/serviceworker-cookbook/blob/master/request-deferrer/service-worker.js` (scroll to the bottom to see the serial/deserialize methods)